# ASP.NET Core model binding values are null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have the following code where I am looping through a property in the model object as follows. The `BlogDataItems` is of type

```
public IPagedList<BlogData> BlogDataItems { get; set; }
```

from using X.PagedList library. I am able to see the Image, title, body etc the values I am binding.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BlogDataItems)
{
    <!-- === Blog item 1 === -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 m-bottom-40">
        <div class="blog wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.7s">
            <div class="blog-media">
                <a href="blog_single_post.html">
                    @*<img src="~/img/blog/b1.jpg" alt="" asp-append-version="true">*@
                    <img id="ItemPreview" src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(item.ImageData)" alt="Image" height="200" width="220" />
                </a>
            </div><!--post media-->

            <div class="blog-post-info clearfix">
                <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostedDateTime)</span>
                @*<span class="comments"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 4 Comments</a></span>*@
            </div><!--post info-->

            <div class="blog-post-body">
                <h4><a class="title" href="blog_single_post.html">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BlogTitle)</a></h4>
                <p class="p-bottom-20">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BlogContent)</p>
                <a class="read-more" asp-action="DetailedView" asp-controller="BlogData" asp-route-blogItem="@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["item"]">Read More >></a>
            </div><!--post body-->
        </div> <!-- /.blog -->
    </div> <!-- /.inner-col -->
}
```

Now please see the 'a class="read-more"' element, I am trying to bind the item using `asp-route-blogItem="@item"` to the controller action method and all the values inside are either null or default. Please help.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DetailedView(BlogData blogItem)
{
    if (blogItem != null)
    {
    }

    return View(blogItem);
}
```

When I debug the code, this is what I have

[image: Values are null or default]

Comment: Why your GET method accepting a model? Do you pass some values in the query string?

Comment: Ok I have updated my code to pass the item as query string and I still have the same issue. Please see the updated post, I am saying asp-route-blogItem="@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["item"] but still have the issue. When I see the URL I can see the query string. Can i say "item" in the quotes like that?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Don't know if there is a better way.,

I am passing in the Item id to the controller <a class="read-more" asp-action="DetailedView" asp-controller="BlogData" asp-route-blogItemId="@item.Id">Read More >></a>

Now in the controller I am finding the item from the list matching the Id.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement,I think you could try `asp-all-route-data` instead of `asp-route-yourkey`

I tried as below :

```
@{
    var id = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["id"];
    var routedata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    routedata.Add("id", id);
    routedata.Add("BlogTitle", "title");
    routedata.Add("BlogContent", "content");

}

.........

<a class="read-more" asp-action="Privacy" asp-controller="Home"  asp-all-route-data="@routedata">Read More >></a>
```

The Result:

[image]

you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0) about modelbinding,and [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-form-action-tag-helper) about taghelper